# Why is the inner product always real?

Tags: inner-products

Seems like we could redefine inner products to map to the imagenary set.

Why is the inner product always real or not surjective?

It seems too convienient and magical to me for inner products to always be real.

It feels like there is something deep about this, or it could be just a simple idea that needs 7 years of brainwashing from a math curriculum to appriciate.

Comment: Inner products on complex inner product spaces can take complex values (i.e. with an imaginary part).

Comment: We can absolutely define an inner product that maps some products to the complex numbers.  e.g. $\langle u,v\rangle = u^\dagger v$ (Where $\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose).  However $\langle u,u\rangle = \|u\|^2$ must be real and satisfy the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your space is real, you only have real numbers to play with. That's why the usual inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ is defined as $$\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k.$$

That's not the case as soon as you have complex numbers at hand. On $\mathbb C^n$, you usually define 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\overline{y_k}. 
$$
The theory of Hilbert spaces and its linear operators is more neat and complete on complex spaces.